# React Hooks: Is clearing/setting a timeout in "local state" like this bad?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am more or less doing this in a functional component:

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

const startTimer = ()=>{
    setTimer(setTimeout(()=>console.log("done"), 10000);
}
const clearTimer = ()=>{
    if(timer){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        setTimer(null);

    }
}
```

I'm wondering if it's wrong or bad practice to mutate `timer` with `clearTimeout()` - should it only be changed with the `setTimer()` method, similar to how state should only be mutated with `setState()`? If it is, is there an alternative way of clearing a timer stored in my component's local state? I did some basic testing and it looks like it's behaving how I want it, but who knows...

Comment: there's a section in the react docs about this exact thing https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Comment: The `clearTimeout` does not mutate `timer`, it just clears the timeout, so the answer to your question is that it's OK because you're not mutating the state. However, it's better to use `useRef` if you don't need to re-render the component when the value of `timer` changes.